# Combo Box font family to Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

i have created combo box with all the windows system fonts on my system, they get listed in the combobox.  i want to take the selected value from the combobox and tell TextBox.Fontfamily (in c# back end) to use the selected font for the TextBox.  i have tried all kind's of conversions, and tried to use font converter (dont fully understand converter).
also binding seems a long difficult unnecessary process.
i am also legally blind and try to stay away from long drawn out
blotted code. like binding.

why can't it just be as easy as the code listed below?

```
(string)tmp2 = (string)combo2.SelectedValue.ToString();
         Textbox . FontFamily = tmp2;
```

Comment: Please tag your question with `WPF` There are many textboxes in many frameworks. By putting WPF on the tag, you are more likely to get WPF experts to look

Comment: I'm not a WPF person. But looking at the WPF textbox control, I don't see a FontFamily property. I do see a Typography property and it has a FontFamily property

Comment: there is a Font Family property.  TextBox.FontFamily="Arial"  for Etc... but what i am am trying to do is get the selected value from Combo Box and give that value to Textbox.FontFamily as a variable.  C#, WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the name of the family of the font correctly, then like this:

```
string tmp2 = (string)combo2.SelectedValue.ToString();
Textbox.FontFamily = new FontFamily(tmp2);
```